# seleniumでスクレイピングをする際、xpathのループの仕方がわかりません。

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

**実行環境**
windows10
python3
jupyterlab

**前提・実現したいこと**

ツイキャスのランキングから配信者の名前とtwitterのリンクをseleniumを使用し
スクレイピングしたいと考えています。

xpathの一部を変えてループをしようとした段階でエラーが起きてしまいました。

**実際のコード**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) #ブラウザを立ち上げる
url = 'https://twitcasting.tv/rankingindex.php'
browser.get(url) #指定のurlに移動

sleep(3)
elems_name = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("tw-ranking-username") #指定のクラスを取得
keys = []
for elem_name in elems_name:
    key = elem_name.text #クラスの中身をテキストで順に取得
    keys.append(key)     #keysに格納
print(keys)
sleep(3)
Turls = []
for i in range(100):
    urls = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rankbox_like"]/div/div[1 + i]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a').get_attribute('href') #xPath変化あり
    browser.get(urls)
    url1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainwrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[11]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a[1]').get_attribute('href') #xPath変化なし
    browser.get(url1)

    Turl = browser.current_url#twitterURL取得
    Turls.append(Turl)
    sleep(3)
    browser.get(url) #元に戻る
```

**エラー内容**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3ea53e55222f> in <module>
     17 Turls = []
     18 for i in range(100):
---> 19     urls = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rankbox_like"]/div/div[1 + i]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a').get_attribute('href') #xPath変化あり
     20     browser.get(urls)
     21     url1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainwrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[11]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a[1]').get_attribute('href') #xPath変化なし

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    392             element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    393         """
--> 394         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    395 
    396     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    974                 by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
--> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
    978             'value': value})['value']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="rankbox_like"]/div/div[1 + i]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)
```

おそらくxpathをループで回そうとするところが間違っていると思うのですが、
正しいやり方がわかりません。

もし解決策がわかる人は教えてください。

また、pythonは初心者でコードがあまり宜しく見えないかとも思われます。
もしこうしたほうがいいというのがあったら教えてください。

Comment: ツイキャスランキングのページソースを見ると、Ajax でランキングページをロードしています(`load_tab_contents()`関数)。その処理を眺めてみると、`https://twitcasting.tv/rankingajax.php?d=20210801&type=daily&genre=&limit=100&cat=like` の内容をロードしている事が判ります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えてもらったリンクでスクレイピングするとやりやすいことがわかりました。　Ajaxでランキングページをロードしているのがわかるのはどこを見るとわかるか教えてほしいです。　@metropolis

Comment: 手元では Google Chrome を使っているのですが、`view-source:https://twitcasting.tv/rankingindex.php` でアクセスして `1276` 行目にある `function load_tab_contents(category)` になります。

Comment: 非常に勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。@metropolis